# Applying filters using gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to use gmail api to apply filters to my inbox. I can only see support to create labels. Can you help me to understand how i can create filters and apply labels for emails which match the filters?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The filter criterion describes a search query. One could get all threads matching that search query and execute the effect of the filter.

I have a simple example here. We use a simple filter that adds a label if the subject matches a string. This example could be extended to cover arbitrary filters.

As @Tholle mentioned, I also was not able to find a simple "run this filter on existing messages" api call.

```
def createFilter(service,userId,o):
    r = service.users().settings().filters().create(
        userId=userId,body=o).execute()
    print("Created filter {}".format(r.get("id")))
    return r

def getMatchingThreads(service,userId,labelIds,query):
    """Get all threads from gmail that match the query"""

    response = service.users().threads().list(userId=userId,labelIds=labelIds,
        q=query).execute()
    threads = []
    if 'threads' in response:
        threads.extend(response['threads'])

    # Do the response while there is a next page to receive.
    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
        pageToken = response['nextPageToken']
        response = service.users().threads().list(
            userId=userId,
            labelIds=labelIds,
            q=query,
            pageToken=pageToken).execute()
        threads.extend(response['threads'])

    return threads

def buildSearchQuery(criteria):
    """Input is the criteria in a filter object. Iterate over it and return a
    gmail query string that can be used for thread search"""

    queryList = []
    positiveStringKeys = ["from","to","subject"]
    for k in positiveStringKeys:
        v = criteria.get(k)
        if v is not None:
            queryList.append("("+k+":"+v+")")

    v = criteria.get("query")
    if v is not None:
        queryList.append("("+v+")")

    # TODO: This can be extended to include other queries. Negated queries,
    # non-string queries

    return " AND ".join(queryList)

def applyFilterToMatchingThreads(service,userId,filterObject):
    """After creating the filter we want to apply it to all matching threads
    This function searches all threads with the criteria and appends the same
    label of the filter"""

    query = buildSearchQuery(filterObject["criteria"])
    threads = getMatchingThreads(service,userId,[],query)

    addLabels = filterObject["action"]["addLabelIds"]
    print("Adding labels {} to {} threads".format(addLabels,len(threads)))

    for t in threads:
        body = {
            "addLabelIds": addLabels,
            "removeLabelIds": []
        }
        service.users().threads().modify(userId=userId,id=t["id"],
            body=body).execute()


# Create your service like in here
# https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

desiredFilters = [
    {
        "criteria": {
          "subject": "[JIRA]",
        },
        "action": {
          "addLabelIds": [labelNameToId["jira"]],
        }
    },
]
for df in desiredFilters:
    createFilter(service,"me",df)
    applyFilterToMatchingThreads(service,"me",df)
```

This is not a complete push-button working example. You need to create your own service object and do OAUTH2 authentication first.

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply filters to your Inbox with the Gmail API. The Gmail API gives RESTful access to drafts, history, labels, messages, attachments, threads and the ability to watch the mailbox to receive push notifications.

You can [create filters with the admin sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_a_filter).

Comment: i tried that, but looks like ClientLogin is deprecated   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps

Comment: @Noobdev I guess the ClientLogin has been deprecated, but one can create filters via the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/create). Is there still no way to "apply" / "run" filters via the Gmail API ?  I am looking to achieve the same thing as the  "Also apply filter to matching conversations" selection in the filter creation GUI.

Comment: @Noobdev I guess one could do the same search defined in the filter via the GUI and [append the right labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#applying_labels_to_messages_and_threads) programmatically too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the filters into url as Query Parameter.

Let suppose you want to filter all messages/thread from a specific user then you can apply from:otheruser@gmail.com filter (whom messages you want to get) in request url.

for Example:

> `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/your_email_id@gmail.com/messages?q=from:otherUser@gmail.com`

It will return all threads received from otherUser@gmail.com